# how to add "<" in front the string in php

Tags: php

Hi I know how to add something in front of the string in php like;

```
$namelast = "+".$names1.">;";
```

it gives me this result

```
+rickandmorty@hotmail.com>;+ricky@hotmail.com>;
```

but I need to add "<" but when I added it gives me nothing I expect to take

```
 <rickandmorty@hotmail.com><ricky@hotmail.com>;
```

so how can I add "<" before the string

Comment: You mean that when you print the string on a web page nothing is shown? Because in that case you need to print `<` as `&lt;` instead

Comment: Thank you Federico klez Culloca !!!

Comment: Like Fereico above said. Printing/echoing "<" would be like adding code to the html and will not allways be visible to the user. You need to use the character entity of it ("&lt")

Comment: There is a function for this, http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php.

Answer (score 0):

```
$tab='&lt';
$namelast = "Welcome ".$tab."";
```

Comment: `&lt` is incorrect. You could copy paste the comment above that lists the correct answer. Your answer should have some context to it.